# Late binding in query

Tags: vb.net, linq, datarow, option-strict

Yes I know what `Option Strict` does and I use it quite often. My issue is stemming from my `Linq` query and I can't seem to figure out how to get it from throwing up. I am wanting to get all `DataRows` in a given table where a row's id equals an id I give it. Also this query works just fine without `Option Strict` on a I get the rows I need, but I want to have it on.

The error: **Option Strict on disallow's late binding**

**Here's what I have right now...**

```
  Dim cRows() As DataRow = (From cRow In MasterDataSet.Tables(1).Rows Where cRow(childTableKey) = intParID).ToArray
```

The error is happening underneath: **cRow(childTableKey)**

I know what the error mean's as well, but can't seem to figure how to stop it from seeing it as an error. I have tried casting it and such already as well...

Comment: You need to cast the row's value to an integer.  Does this work for you?  `Where Cint(cRow(childTableKey)) = intParID`

Comment: @ps2goat no it doesn't I have tried that, thanks though.

Comment: It's great that you're familiar with Option Strict...but what error are you receiving?

Comment: @Greg sorry about that I removed it from my title and was going to put that in my post and forgot...

Comment: Try doing a `ToList` -- I think I had issues with a RowCollection and LINQ before. Converting it to a list gets rid of that issue. `From cRow In MasterDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.ToList()`

Comment: @ps2goat that doesn't work as "ToList()" isn't a member of rows...

Comment: Try `From cRow In MasterDataSet.Tables(1).AsEnumerable()...`.

Comment: @Mark "AsEnumerable" isn't a member of DataTable...

Comment: Sorry, should have linked to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You need to reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.

Comment: Also, you usually need `Option Infer On` for LINQ, but maybe you already have that, can't tell.

Comment: This seems to be unrealated to `Option Stict` instruction...

Comment: @Mark, you don't need `Option Infer On` for LINQ.

Comment: @Mark well I'll be darn! It was because the "System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" wasn't in the references. We updated a project to the 4.0 framework recently from 2.0 I guess it didn't carry these over, but that was it! Thanks!

Comment: @Mark also the reason it was working in my test solution was because it was a new project which included these references...

Comment: @ps2goat Thanks!  I would have sworn I've run into issues with that, but maybe it was related to anonymous types?

Comment: @Mark, yes that would be it.  We tend to steer away from anonymous types because of the confusion they can cause.  You can always use a `Tuple`, but it's just as easy to create your own object and retain clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
In MasterDataSet.Tables(1) Where CType(cRow(childTableKey), Integer)
```

instead of

```
In MasterDataSet.Tables(1).Rows Where cRow(childTableKey)
```

The example below is working for me with Option Strict:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim dc As New DataColumn
    dc.DataType = GetType(System.Int32)
    dt.Columns.Add(dc)
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    dr(0) = 10
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    Dim rows As DataRow() = (From r In ds.Tables(0) Where CType(r(0), Integer) = 10).ToArray
```

Comment: Have you tried both not using .Rows and casting cRow(childTableKey) as integer? Do you have the System.Data.DataSetExtensions reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim filteredTable1Data= MasterDataSet.Tables(1).AsEnumerable().
    Where(Function(r) r.Field(of Integer)("childTableKey")=intParID)
```

For further information, please see:
[Queries in LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
[LINQ to DataSet Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without additional extensions, you need to copy the rows from the `RowCollection` to an `Array`. Then you can use LINQ.

```
Dim myRows(-1) as DataRow
MasterDataSet.Tables(1).Rows.CopyTo(myRows, 0)

 Dim cRows() As DataRow = (From cRow In myRows 
    Where CInt(cRow(childTableKey)) = intParID).ToArray()
```